# /stats is broken on OnStartups

Tags: bug, status-completed, statistics

The following URL is returning an object that is missing some data:

> http://api.onstartups.stackexchange.com/1.1/stats

The entire `site` object is missing from the returned data. Other sites, such as Math.SE, return the `site` object:

```
"site": {
    "name": "Mathematics",
    ...
}
```

**However,** this data is being returned for OnStartups in the `/sites` method:

```
"main_site": {
    "name": "OnStartups",
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed, as of the last deploy.